# How to create a new instance of Selenium Webdiver for each thread in a Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, parallel.foreach

I want to run a parallel execution of a crawler using Selenium ChromeDriver.

If I use the same instance of ChromeDriver in the `ForEach` loop I run into problems.

When trying to access attributes of a HTML document I get the exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

probably because another thread modifies the state of the instance before the current thread can read it.

Here is what I have now:

```
public class ChromeCrawler : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ChromeDriver _driver;

    public ChromeCrawler()
    {
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }

    public string GetHTML(string url)
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        var html = _driver.FindElementsByTagName("html");
        var content = html.First().GetAttribute("innerHTML");    //<----- Here I get the exception

        return content;
    }
    ....
}

var crawler = new ChromeCrawler();

//Execution
Parallel.ForEach(pages_list, page_url =>
{
    var html = crawler.GetHTML(page_url );
    .....
});
```

Is there a way to create a new instance of `ChromeCrawler` for each thread of the `Parallel.ForEach`?

Answer (score 0):

Store your drivers in a list in a separate class, intended to keep track of all the drivers currently executing in parallel. In my case, I have a class called BrowserController, which tracks the current driver instances and handles both creation and removal of the drivers. It uses a function like this to add a new driver:

```
    public Dictionary<string, RemoteWebDriver> Drivers;

    public RemoteWebDriver AddDriver(string testName, string url, ICapabilities capabilities)
    {
        var driver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>(() =>
        {
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(url), capabilities);
        }).Value;

        Drivers.Add(testName, driver);

        TestBase.StaticLogInfo($"Added driver for test: {testName}");
        return Drivers[testName];
    }
```